# Gracefully stop Logback in container environment

Tags: tomcat, out-of-memory, logback, permgen, redeploy

Today I get `PermGen OutOfMemory` error.

Analysis shown that *Nearest GC Root* for `WebappClassLoader` is Logback thread:

```
this     - value: org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader #4
  <- contextClassLoader (thread object)     - class: java.lang.Thread, value: org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader #4
```

which is:

```
java.lang.Thread#11 - logback-1
```

Thread dump from heap dump for this thread:

```
"logback-1" daemon prio=5 tid=34 WAITING
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:458)
at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:359)
   Local Variable: java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack$SNode#1
   Local Variable: java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack#6
at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.take(SynchronousQueue.java:925)
   Local Variable: java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue#6
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
   Local Variable: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor#34
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
   Local Variable: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker#11
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I use Tomcat 8 with hot redeploy feature `reloadable="true"` and externalized `CLASSPATH` via `PreResources`:

```
<Context docBase="/home/user/devel/app/src/main/webapp"
         reloadable="true">
    <Resources>
        <!-- To override application.properties and logback.xml -->
        <PreResources className="org.apache.catalina.webresources.DirResourceSet"
                       base="/home/user/devel/app/.config"
                       internalPath="/"
                       webAppMount="/WEB-INF/classes" />
    </Resources>
</Context>
```

and `logback.xml` with `scan="true"`:

```
<configuration debug="false" scan="true" scanPeriod="5 seconds">
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    ...
```

After saving modification in `/home/user/devel/app/.config/logback.xml` Tomcat 8 receive notification (I am not sure what API used to monitor  changes on fs) and application redeploying was started. That is what happen before `PermGen OutOfMemory`.

How can I Gracefully stop Logback in container environment?

How to stop `"logback-1"` thread?

I found a few related discussion but can't understand what to do with that info:

- http://logback.10977.n7.nabble.com/How-to-stop-all-appenders-td3023.html
- [Do I need to flush events when shutting down using logback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678755/do-i-need-to-flush-events-when-shutting-down-using-logback)
- [Correct way to stop custom logback async appender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31415899/correct-way-to-stop-custom-logback-async-appender)
- [Stopping Logback System for Clean Shutdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16795299/stopping-logback-system-for-clean-shutdown)

**UPDATE** I play with heap dump in `visualvm`. Under level of reference jump from bad `logback-1` thread:

```
lvl1 = flatten(filter(referees(heap.findObject(0xf4c77610)), "!/WebappClassLoader/(classof(it).name)"))

lvl2 = flatten(map(lvl1, "referees(it)"))

lvl3 = flatten(map(lvl2, "referees(it)"))
```

it refer to

```
ch.qos.logback.core.util.ExecutorServiceUtil$1
```

By grepping in Logback sources for `ExecutorServiceUtil` I [found changelog entry](http://logback.qos.ch/news.html):

> All threads opened by
>   ch.qos.logback.core.util.ExecutorServiceUtil#THREAD_FACTORY are
>   now daemons, which fixes an application hang on shutdown when
>   LoggerContext#stop() is not called (LOGBACK-929). Note that
>   daemon threads are abruptly terminated by the JVM, which may
>   cause undesirable results, such as corrupted files written by the
>   FileAppender. It is still highly recommended for the application
>   to call LoggerContext#stop() (e.g., in a shutdown hook) to
>   gracefully shutdown appenders.

Is that right that in container environment daemon threads are danger and lead to memory leaks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not fully understand what should I do. Currently I remove `jul-to-slf4j` bridge from project `pom.xml` and this line:

```
<contextListener class="ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator"/>
```

from `logback.xml`. Even with this line application have no `"logback-1"` thread.

[As suggest official docs](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#stopContext) I register:

```
public class ShutdownCleanupListener implements ServletContextListener {
    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) { }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        if (LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory() instanceof LoggerContext) {
            ((LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory() ).stop();
        } 
    }
}
```

in `web.xml`:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.app.servlet.ShutdownCleanupListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

To remove direct dependency on:

```
import ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext;
```

reflection may be used.

Not sure if I am doing right. I will see if get `PermGen OutOfMemory` error because of Logback.

**UPDATE** After I have discovered reference dependency from `ExecutorServiceUtil` class I checked Logback sources and found that this class create threads with names like bad above:

```
 thread.setName("logback-" + threadNumber.getAndIncrement());
```

This class only used in `ch.qos.logback.core.ContextBase` and thread leaned up inside:

```
public void stop() {
  // We don't check "started" here, because the executor service uses
  // lazy initialization, rather than being created in the start method
  stopExecutorService();
  started = false;
}
```

Note that `LoggerContext` is subclass of `ContextBase` so **above solution really fix my problem**.

Comment: Thanks this fixed my WebappClassLoader leak as well!

Answer (score 2):

According to the Spring Boot logback example project, you should close the context to clean up the logging system: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/10402a651f1ee51704b58985c7ef33619df2c110

Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(SampleLogbackApplication.class, args).close();
    }
```

Comment: As I understand your solution is applicable only for Spring Boot enabled applications...

Answer (score 1):

> Is that right that in container environment daemon threads are danger and lead to memory leaks?

The statement about daemon threads refer to the case of a stand alone application (as in the [bug report](http://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-929)), where the JVM is supposed to shut down when the application is finished. The non-daemon thread prevents the JVM from shutting down.

In a JavaEE context, where the JVM of the application server remains the same over potentially multiple lifecycles of multiple applications, daemon vs non-daemon does not affect the fact that [live threads are GC roots](http://java.jiderhamn.se/2012/01/15/classloader-leaks-iii-die-thread-die/).